# How to display output in a machine learning web app

Tags: python, html, flask, backend

I have built a wep app & a machine learning model for prediction. The user shall select input variables from web app, the model will predict the values. I am using flask for linking both of them. I am unable to figure a way to print the numerical value (predicted value) in a pop up box in the web app. Please someone tell me the syntax for the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options depending on what you want.
A simple alert would do the trick for debugging:

```
window.alert('your output');
```

If you want a bit more control over the look and feel, you could go with a classic message box/snackbar. W3Schools got a great tutorial for those:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp

Or did you mean how to build a complete message box with HTML and CSS?